# Using Interrupts with Sense Hat

Tags: gpio, sensor, interrupts, sense-hat

Im trying to use the Interrupts on the Sense hat (preferably in combination with the IMU), but i get this error

> GPIO.add_event_detect(INTERRUPT1, GPIO.FALLING,callback=my_callback1,bouncetime=300)
> RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection

Using the pinout from [this website](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/sense_hat#) i know the Interrupts are on GPIO 23 and 24. I havent found anything about using those interrupts so i wanted to write something simple, but its still not working. Is it even possible to trigger a interrupt with just the output method? How do i use those interrupts in combination with the IMU sensor? Any help is appreciated

```
#SENSOR IMPORTS
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

sense = SenseHat()
sense.set_imu_config(False, False, True)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
INTERRUPT1 = 23

def my_callback1():
    print("Falling Edge detected")

GPIO.setup(INTERRUPT1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down= GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(INTERRUPT1, GPIO.FALLING,callback=my_callback1,bouncetime=300)


try:
    print("Setting edge to high")
    GPIO.output(INTERRUPT1, False)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
finally:
GPIO.cleanup()
```

EDIT:
new error after GPIO.cleanup() after GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

> interrupt.py:9: RuntimeWarning: No channels have been set up yet -
> nothing to clean up!  Try cleaning up at the end of your program
> instead!   GPIO.cleanup() Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/pi/.../interrupt.py", line 16, in 
> GPIO.add_event_detect(INTERRUPT1, GPIO.FALLING,callback=my_callback1,bouncetime=300) RuntimeError:
> Failed to add edge detection

Comment: What happens if you comment out the two sense hat lines?

Comment: the same error occurs

Comment: I suggest you try doing a GPIO.cleanup() after you do the setmode.  Other than that try another library.

Comment: the error actually changes i put it in an EDIT in the post, but yes, i will probably use another library like smbus or something for i2c